# Best Practice for Updating AWS ECS Service Tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I'm currently attempting to set up a simple CI that will rebuild my project, create a new docker image, push the new image to an amazon ecr repo, create a new revision of an existing task definition with the latest docker image, update a running service with the new revision of the task definition, and finally stop the existing task running the old revision and start one running the new revision.

Everything is working fine except for starting the new revision of the task.

From a bash script, the final command I call is:

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster "$CLUSTER" --service "$SERVICE" --task-definition "$TASK_DEFINITION":"$REVISION"
```

This results in an event error of:

```
(service rj-api-service) was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching (container-instance bbbc23d5-1a09-45e7-b344-e68cc408e683) is already using a port required by your task.
```

And this makes sense because the container I am replacing is exactly sthe same as the new one and will be running on the same port, it just contains the latest version of my application.

I was under the impression the `update-service` command would stop the existing task, and start the new one, but it looks like it starts the new one first, and if it succeeds stops the old one.

What is the best practice for handling this? Should I stop the old task first? Should I just delete the service  in my script first and   recreate the entire service each update?

Currently I only need 1 instance of the task running, but I don't want to box my self in if I need this to be able to auto scale to multiple instances. Any suggestions on the best way to address this?

Comment: "If a revision is not specified, the latest ACTIVE revision is used."  according to the [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html#options)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The message that you are getting is because ECS is trying to do a blue-green deployment. It means that it is trying to allocate your new task revision without stopping the current task to avoid downtime in your service. Once the newest task is ready (steady state), the old one will be finally removed.

The problem with this type of deployment is that you need to have enough **free resources** in your cluster in order maintain up and running the 2 tasks (old and new one) for a period of time. For example, if you are deploying a task with 2GB of memory and 2 CPUs, your cluster will need to have that amount of free resources in order to update the service with a new task revision.

You have 2 options:

1. Scale up your cluster by adding a new EC2 instance so you can have enough free resources and perform the deployment.
2. Change your service configuration in order to do not perform a blue-green deployment (allow only 1 task at the same time in your cluster).

In order to perform option number 2 you only need to set the following values:

- **Minimum healthy percent**: 0
- **Maximum percent**: 100

*Example*

[image: Example]

Which means that you only want to have 100% of your desired tasks running (and no more!) and you are willing to have a downtime while you deploy a new version (0% of healthy service).

*In the example I am assuming that you only want 1 desired task, but the **Minimum healthy percent** and **Maximum percent** values will work for any amount of desired tasks you want.*

Hope it helps! Let me know if you have any other doubt.

Comment: This is a perfect description. Thank you so much. I had the the healthy percent set to the defaults of 50/200. I'm fine with not doing a blue-green deployment so setting the  healthy percent to 0/100 works how I originally expected it would and all I have to call is update with out the extra steps of stoping the running task.

Comment: So in case of min 0 and max 100 and i have 3 containers running, will an update do a rolling upgrade or it will kill all 3 of my containers and start a set of 3.

Comment: It should kill your running containers first, and then start the latest ones (perform the update).

Comment: I have the above setup with the Minimum Healthy Percentage and the Maximum Percent, however, I still get the error  was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements.The closes matching (xxx) is already using a port required by your task.

Comment: @fuzzi hi, I run into this issue too, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @TonyV. for me, I found that Stopping the running Task, and then Starting the new Task solved the issue.  However, I changed the percentages to Minimum healthy percent 25 and Maximum percent 200 so that I wouldn't need to outright Stop the Running Task.

Comment: This error does relate to resource exhaustion, but with the current version of ECS and tools available, you do not require scaling the cluster's nodes at all.  If your task definition sets both a Container port AND a Host port, it will not dynamically allocate the port for your container, and you will see this error if your cluster only has 1 node, since only one thing can use the same port.  But set Host port to 0, and it will be dynamic and you can spawn multiple different versions in a single-node cluster without port conflicts provided enough available resources for both on the node.

Comment: @fuzzi There are many requirements that must be met to place a task. You must consider CPU, Memory, ENIs, ports, GPUs, placement constraints, etc. It sounds like you're statically assigning a `Host port` in a container definition in your task definition. This means that port resource is occupied and it cannot start another service that needs that same port. You can omit the host port parameter for it to be assigned a host port automatically. A load balancer will do the work of discovering the host port and routing traffic to the container on the specified port.

Answer (score 8):

You can start the new revision of tasks with the following steps using a shell script in your build environment.

1. Store the [tasks definition json template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-task-definition.html) in your build environment in a file (for e.g template file is `web-server.json` and task definition family is `web-server`).
2. Use the file directory as current directory and execute register task definition(Happens for the first run if not exists)

   `aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://web-server.json`
3. Get the running task id(TASK_ID) to a variable in shell script.

   `` TASK_ID=`aws ecs list-tasks --cluster default --desired-status RUNNING --family web-server | egrep "task" | tr "/" " " | tr "[" " " |  awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/"$//'` ``
4. Get the task revision(TASK_REVISION) to variables in shell script.

   `` TASK_REVISION=`aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition web-server | egrep "revision" | tr "/" " " | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/"$//'` ``
5. Stop the current task running

   `aws ecs stop-task --cluster default --task ${TASK_ID}`
6. Immediately start a new task

   `aws ecs update-service --cluster default --service web-server --task-definition web-server:${TASK_REVISION} --desired-count 1`

As a best practice, you can keep desired-count minimum for 2 tasks( two tasks running inside the service) and do rolling updates(Update one task at a time) using the following script(Extension of above steps for multiple containers) with zero downtime (Make sure you keep sufficient time after first container updates e.g sleep 30 for it to be ready to accept new requests).

```
cd /<directory-containing-web-server.json>
aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://web-server.json
OLD_TASK_ID=`aws ecs list-tasks --cluster default --desired-status RUNNING --family web-server | egrep "task" | tr "/" " " | tr "[" " " |  awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/"$//'`

TASK_REVISION=`aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition web-server | egrep "revision" | tr "/" " " | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/"$//'`
aws ecs stop-task --cluster default --task ${OLD_TASK_ID}

OLD_TASK_ID=`aws ecs list-tasks --cluster default --desired-status RUNNING --family web-server | egrep "task" | tr "/" " " | tr "[" " " |  awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/"$//'`
aws ecs update-service --cluster default --service web-server --task-definition web-server:${TASK_REVISION} --desired-count 1

sleep 30
aws ecs stop-task --task ${OLD_TASK_ID}
aws ecs update-service --cluster default --service web-server --task-definition web-server:${TASK_REVISION} --desired-count 2
```

Note: You need to configure the task definition family, desired-count of instances and task definition template accordingly.

Comment: You ca simplify the line OLD_TASK_ID=... using "jq" 
 ... 
OLD_TASK_ID=`aws ecs list-tasks --cluster default --desired-status RUNNING --family web-server | jq --raw-output ".taskArns | .[]"`
of course you have to install the JQ 'apt-get install jq'

Comment: @Ashan How to get file://web-server.json from existing task definition ?

Answer (score 4):

**Use -> AWS CLI**

Get OLD_TASK_ID

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster ${ecsClusterName} --desired-status RUNNING --family ${nameTaskDefinition} | egrep "task/" | sed -E "s/.*task\/(.*)\"/\1/"
```

Stop TASK

```
aws ecs stop-task --cluster ${ecsClusterName} --task ${OLD_TASK_ID}
```

Update ECS Service

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster ${ecsClusterName} --service ${nameService} --task-definition ${nameTaskDefinition}:${version} --desired-count 1 --force-new-deployment
```

Comment: When parsing JSON, `jq` rules: `aws ecs list-tasks ... | jq ".taskArns[0]"`.

Answer (score 1):

So I do have this working now.

After I call `aws ecs update service` with the new task definition I call `aws ecs list-tasks` and then run 'aws stop task` on each running tasks for the service. Because the desired count for the service is 1, it immediately tries to start the tasks back up and uses the new service definition.

This isn't very pretty but it seem to work well enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

To update a task-definition in the "tasks" running in the service You need to delete the tasks and Start a new task.

In this way, I solve the problem of updating task-definition in tasks

I have written the following code :

```
    # Register a new Task definition 
    aws ecs register-task-definition --family testing-cluster --cli-input-json file://scripts/taskdefinition/testingtaskdef.json --region $AWS_REGION

    # Update Service in the Cluster
    aws ecs update-service --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --service $SERVICE --task-definition testing-cluster --desired-count 1 --region $AWS_REGION 



    DECRIBED_SERVICE=$(aws ecs describe-services --region $AWS_REGION --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --services $SERVICE);
    CURRENT_DESIRED_COUNT=$(echo $DECRIBED_SERVICE | jq --raw-output ".services[0].desiredCount")
    #    - echo $CURRENT_DESIRED_COUNT

    CURRENT_TASK_REVISION=$(echo $DECRIBED_SERVICE | jq -r ".services[0].taskDefinition")
    echo "Current Task definition in Service" + $CURRENT_TASK_REVISION

    CURRENT_RUNNING_TASK=$(echo $DECRIBED_SERVICE | jq -r ".services[0].runningCount")
    echo $CURRENT_RUNNING_TASK

    CURRENT_STALE_TASK=$(echo $DECRIBED_SERVICE | jq -r ".services[0].deployments | .[] | select(.taskDefinition != \"$CURRENT_TASK_REVISION\") | .taskDefinition")
    echo "Task defn apart from current service Taskdefn" +  $CURRENT_STALE_TASK
    #   - echo $CURRENT_STALE_TASK

    tasks=$(aws ecs --region $AWS_REGION list-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME | jq -r '.taskArns | map(.[40:]) | reduce .[] as $item (""; . + $item + " ")')
    echo "Tasks are as follows" 
    echo $tasks
    TASKS=$(aws ecs --region $AWS_REGION describe-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --task $tasks);
    #    - echo $TASKS
    OLDER_TASK=$(echo $TASKS | jq -r ".tasks[] | select(.taskDefinitionArn!= \"$CURRENT_TASK_REVISION\") | .taskArn | split(\"/\") | .[1] ")
    echo "Older Task running  " + $OLDER_TASK
    for old_task in $OLDER_TASK; do
        aws ecs --region us-east-1 stop-task --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --task $old_task
    done    

    # Run new tasks with the updated new Task-definition
    aws ecs --region $AWS_REGION run-task --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --task-definition $CURRENT_TASK_REVISION
```